# setting LANGUAGE_CODE in template based on page setting

Tags: django, wagtail

In Django / Wagtail I can set the language of a single page. With my custom instance method `{{ page.get_language }}` this language is available in the template.

But I want all dates and hard-coded texts translated in the set language. So I would like to to set `LANGUAGE_CODE` with `page.get_language`.

Any ideas what the best practice is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<html class="no-js" lang="{{ page.get_language }}">`

and in your template `{% load i18n %}`

Answer (score 0):

The [`django.utils.translation.activate` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language) selects the language to be used by Django's translation framework, in preference to the default one in `LANGUAGE_CODE` - so, in this case you would use `activate(page.get_language)`.